# AngulartJS does not render

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why the expression is not rendered by AngularJS?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Person</p>
<div mg-app="myApp" ng-init="g=9.8" ng-controller="myCtrl">
First name <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last name <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
Birthday <input type="date" ng-model="birthday"><br>
{{firstName+' '+lastName}} was born on {{birthday}}  
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
    $scope.birthday= "2015/1/1";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It gives

> {{firstName+' '+lastName}} was born on {{birthday}}

instead of expression evaluation

Comment: It's just a spelling mistake in your code... You gave it as `mg-app="myApp"`... Its `ng-app="myApp"`

Comment: You have a TYPO in your code: `mg-app` should be `ng-app` => see initial `m`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spelling error:

```
mg-app => ng-app
```

Comment: Thank you. That was embarrassing.

Comment: @PaulVerest It's easy to forget. I suggest you to put some effort next time you post a question, and describe what you have tried to do in order to solve it. Most likely, more people will happily help you then!

Comment: I believe it is job of tool to point at such error.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Person</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="g=9.8" ng-controller="myCtrl">
First name <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last name <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
Birthday <input type="date" ng-model="birthday"><br>
{{firstName}} {{lastName}} was born on {{birthday}}
  
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
    $scope.birthday= "2015/1/1";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation on what the changes are and why they now works  (even in code comments) would improve this answer